# Order of difference between Distribution function and Its empirical

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, estimation

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d with distribution function $F$. Let $\hat F_n$ be its empirical distribution function, i.e.,
$$
\hat F_n(x)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n1_{\{X_\le x\}}(x)
$$
where $1_A(x)$ is the characteristic function.

I am going to know the order of 
$$
T_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\{\Phi^{-1}(\hat F_n(X_i))\}^2-\{\Phi^{-1}(F(X_i))\}^2\right)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the comulative normal standard distribution function.

I have feeling that $T_n=o_p(\sqrt n)$ since for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ I have $\{\Phi^{-1}(\hat F_n(x))\}^2-\{\Phi^{-1}(F(x))\}^2=O_p(1/\sqrt n)$. However, I cannot extend to determine the order of $T_n$ since $\hat F_n$ also depends on $X_i$. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by the "order" of a statistic.  Do you mean its asymptotic behavior as $n$ increases?

Comment: Yes @whuber. It means the behaviour when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Something like this?  https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.35.5.252